# Validations in Struts2 for Integer value?

Tags: java, regex, struts2, struts-validation

I want to maintain length of contact number(Like mobile number in between 10 and 12 digits number ). When I used String type I got but it allows alphabets along with numbers also. I want to prevent  alphabets. How can I do with integer.

Below is my code:

```
@StringLengthFieldValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,message="contact should contain min
of 10 numbers and max 12 numbers",minLength="10",maxLength="12")
private String contact;
```

Now I want for Integer type to do the same as above. How can I do

```
@ ?
private int contact;
```

Comment: I remember an annotation named `@pattern` which can do regexp in it. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with regex field validator. It validates numbers against the given pattern.

```
@RegexFieldValidator(regex = "\\d{10,12}", message="contact should contain min
of 10 numbers and max 12 numbers")
```